# Facebook: We've disabled this app for violating the Facebook Platform Policies

Tags: android, ios, facebook-login

I am an iOS developer, and FB developer account for both iOS and android. I have integrated `pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'` and followed FB developer account for procedure then FB login was worked in app but after some days got like this if i login to fb

> App not active: This app is not currently accessible and the app developer is aware of the issue. you will be able to log in when the app is reactivated

I have checked my developer account > settings > basic-- there all links(privacy policy and terms & conditions and web site links) are active and working

I got only one warning something like below.. what is the solution for this.. I am unable to catch the reason for app disable

please guide me to solve this

**is this is the reason for app disable**
[Developer account with error message screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbwDK.png)

got this msg in dashboard > alert > inbox--- same msg in mail as well but all URLs are working in dashobard

To keep the Facebook platform and community safe, apps are periodically reviewed for compliance.

A request for information was sent to myapp@gmail.com because a compliance review could not be completed for MyApp (138787897).

We have not received a response to the request or the information needed to complete the review. As a result, MyApp has been disabled.

Details about the information requested as well as how to respond can be found in the email.

If you haven't received the email:
Ensure the email address listed in your App Dashboard is correct for any future correspondence.
You can appeal the restriction here.

Comment: I don't think the app-ads.txt warning has anything to do with the app being disabled. However, if you do want to get rid of that warning message, follow the troubleshooting guide here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/optimization/best-practices/troubleshoot-app-ads/ 
There seems to be a link in the red warning box that links to the Developer Appeals page. Perhaps follow that and see if you can find the reasons for the ban?

Comment: Hi @Swift iOS Were you able to fix this issue? I'm having the same issue.